# python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully. WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -yaudio

Tags: warnings, setuptools, setup.py, pyaudio, egg

I need some help please... I tried to instal pydictionary and it give me the same errors and warnings. And for anything else the Warning is the same and I can not understand why. I went to that directory to see what is in there but is empty.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install PyDictionary
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -yaudio (c:\users\robi\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -yaudio (c:\users\robi\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
Collecting PyDictionary
  Using cached PyDictionary-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (6.1 kB)
Collecting goslate
  Using cached goslate-1.5.4.tar.gz (14 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\robi\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from PyDictionary) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click in c:\users\robi\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from PyDictionary) (8.1.3)
Collecting bs4
  Using cached bs4-0.0.1.tar.gz (1.1 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\robi\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from bs4->PyDictionary) (4.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\robi\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from click->PyDictionary) (0.4.4)
Collecting futures
  Using cached futures-3.0.5.tar.gz (25 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 14, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Robi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 247, in <module>
          monkey.patch_all()
        File "C:\Users\Robi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 97, in patch_all
          patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
        File "C:\Users\Robi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 157, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
          patch_func(*msvc14('_get_vc_env'))
        File "C:\Users\Robi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 147, in patch_params
          mod = import_module(mod_name)
        File "C:\Users\Robi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "C:\Users\Robi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 20, in <module>
          import unittest.mock as mock
        File "C:\Users\Robi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 26, in <module>
          import asyncio
        File "C:\Users\Robi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
          from .base_events import *
        File "C:\Users\Robi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 18, in <module>
          import concurrent.futures
        File "C:\Users\Robi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jx1giu6v\futures_b2c696095539418c98c7048813756f80\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
          from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
        File "C:\Users\Robi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jx1giu6v\futures_b2c696095539418c98c7048813756f80\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 357
          raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback
                                     ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -yaudio (c:\users\robi\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -yaudio (c:\users\robi\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -yaudio (c:\users\robi\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
```

I also tried to see my list and upgrade the setup tools but...
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip list
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -yaudio (c:\users\robi\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
Package                  Version

---

beautifulsoup4           4.11.1
cachetools               5.1.0
calculator1              1.0.0
certifi                  2021.10.8
cffi                     1.15.0
charset-normalizer       2.0.12
click                    8.1.3
colorama                 0.4.4
comtypes                 1.1.11
DateTime                 4.4
distlib                  0.3.4
ez-setup                 0.9
filelock                 3.7.0
Flask                    2.1.2
future                   0.18.2
google-api-core          2.8.0
google-api-python-client 2.48.0
google-auth              2.6.6
google-auth-httplib2     0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib     0.5.1
googleapis-common-protos 1.56.1
gTTS                     2.2.4
httplib2                 0.20.4
idna                     3.3
iso8601                  1.0.2
itsdangerous             2.1.2
Jinja2                   3.1.2
keyboard                 0.13.5
MarkupSafe               2.1.1
MouseInfo                0.1.3
numpy                    1.23.4
oauthlib                 3.2.0
Pillow                   9.1.1
pip                      22.3.1
platformdirs             2.5.2
playsound                1.3.0
protobuf                 3.20.1
pyAlarm                  1.0.1
pyasn1                   0.4.8
pyasn1-modules           0.2.8
PyAudio                  0.2.12
PyAutoGUI                0.9.53
pycparser                2.21
PyGetWindow              0.0.9
pyjokes                  0.6.0
PyMsgBox                 1.0.9
pyparsing                3.0.9
pyperclip                1.8.2
pypiwin32                223
PyRect                   0.2.0
PyScreeze                0.1.28
pyserial                 3.5
pyttsx3                  2.90
pytweening               1.0.4
pytz                     2022.1
pywhatkit                5.3
pywin32                  304
PyYAML                   6.0
requests                 2.27.1
requests-oauthlib        1.3.1
rsa                      4.8
scipy                    1.9.3
serial                   0.0.97
setuptools               65.5.1
six                      1.16.0
sounddevice              0.4.4
soupsieve                2.3.2.post1
SpeechRecognition        3.8.1
uritemplate              4.1.1
urllib3                  1.26.9
virtualenv               20.14.1
Werkzeug                 2.1.2
wheel                    0.38.4
wikipedia                1.4.0
xgboost                  1.7.1
zope.interface           5.4.0
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -yaudio (c:\users\robi\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -yaudio (c:\users\robi\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -yaudio (c:\users\robi\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)

I tried to upgrade pip and tools in cmd but that warning is still there. I uninstall the pyaudio to see if that is the problem but still the same errors. I hope someone can help me with this problem please
I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

If you have visual studio code, try to install the packages from the terminal there. Once the error pops up on the terminal in Visual Studio Code, hold ctrl + click on the path and it should take you to the actual folder. What you then want to do is delete the folders that starts with ~. Hope this helps.